# alocar um ponteiro dentro de uma struct

Tags: c

Nesse exemplo, eu posso alocar o ponteiro de mapa com a função malloc, sem ter erros de acesso a memória? a struct q envolve o ponteiro tb aumenta de tamanho junto com o ponteiro?

```
typedef struct{

    char **mapa;
    int linhas, colunas;

} mapa;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> eu posso alocar o ponteiro de mapa com a funcao malloc, sem ter erros de acesso a memoria?

Declarou duas coisas com o mesmo nome: `mapa`. E um ponteiro não é alocado. Uma área de memória é alocada e o endereço é atribuído a um ponteiro, porque se não for a área vai ficar alocada mas inacessível.

> a struct q envolve o ponteiro tb aumenta de tamanho junto com o ponteiro?

Não. A `struct` tem tamanho fixo: o tamanho de dois `int` mais o tamanho de um `char*`.

### EXEMPLO

Considere

```
typedef struct
{
    char** mapa;
    size_t colunas;
    size_t linhas;
} Mapa;
```

prefira o clássico `size_t` em C e nunca vai se surpreender por ter um valor negativo em `linhas` ou `colunas`

E, no estilo `RAII` de `C++` crie ao mesmo tempo funções que criam e destroem `Mapa`. Assim ao declarar um `Mapa` já pode inicializar a memória e o ponteiro, e ao destruir já pode invalidar o tal ponteiro na mesma linha, como abaixo:

```
    Mapa* teste = cria_m(2, 4);
    teste = destroi_m(teste);
```

E já escreva

- algo para mostrar na tela o conteúdo porque vai ter que testar afinal.
- algo para colocar um valor conhecido nas linhas e colunas para saber o que esperar:

#### `mp.h` pode tornar a vida mais simples

```
#pragma once
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    char** mapa;
    size_t colunas;
    size_t linhas;
} Mapa;

Mapa* cria_m(size_t, size_t);
Mapa* destroi_m(Mapa*);
int   mostra_m(Mapa*, const char*);
int   set_m(Mapa*);
```

#### Exemplo: `main.c`

Esse programa cria 2 `Mapa` e mostra na tela os conteúdos

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mp.h"

int main(void)
{
    Mapa* teste = cria_m(2, 4);
    if (teste == NULL) return -1;
    set_m(teste);
    mostra_m(teste, "com valores a partir de 'A'");
    teste = destroi_m(teste);

    teste = cria_m(5, 1);
    if (teste == NULL) return -1;
    set_m(teste);
    mostra_m(teste, "com valores a partir de 'A'");
    teste = destroi_m(teste);
    return 0;
}
```

#### uma implementação de `mp.c`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mp.h"

Mapa* cria_m(size_t l, size_t c)
{
    if (l == 0) return NULL;
    if (c == 0) return NULL;
    Mapa* novo = (Mapa*)malloc(sizeof(Mapa));
    novo->mapa = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * l);
    if (novo == NULL) return NULL;
    for (int y = 0; y < l; y += 1)
        novo->mapa[y] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * c);
    novo->linhas = l;
    novo->colunas = c;
    return novo;
}

Mapa* destroi_m(Mapa* m)
{
    if (m == NULL) return NULL;
    for (int y = 0; y < m->linhas; y += 1) free(m->mapa[y]);
    free(m->mapa);
    free(m);
    return NULL;
};

int mostra_m(Mapa* m, const char* tit)
{ 
    if (m == NULL) return -1;
    if (tit != NULL) printf("%s\n", tit);
    printf("    [%zdx%zd]\n", m->linhas, m->colunas);
    for (size_t l = 0; l < m->linhas; l += 1)
    {
        for (size_t c = 0; c < m->colunas; c += 1)
            printf("%c ", m->mapa[l][c]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    return 0;
};

int set_m(Mapa* teste)
{
    if (teste == NULL) return -1;
    for (int l = 0, i = 0; l < teste->linhas; l += 1)
        for (int c = 0; c < teste->colunas; c += 1)
            teste->mapa[l][c] = 'A' + (i++ % 26);
    return 0;
}
```

#### saída de `main.c` com esse exemplo

```
com valores a partir de 'A'
    [2x4]
A B C D
E F G H


com valores a partir de 'A'
    [5x1]
A
B
C
D
E
```

**Antes** de alguém escrever que não se deve usar `cast` no retorno de `malloc()`: C-FAQ por exemplo recomenda não usar e se trata de uma coletânea de recomendações dos '90, nunca atualizada. Hoje qualquer conversão implícita é desencorajada. E eu, como muitos, evito.